# Running docker container on windows with a volume gives me an error

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to run a simple docker image with a volume

```
docker run -dit -v J:\dvolumes:/data ubuntu
```

However I get the following error

> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: data.

I'm guessing it's thinking the ':' after the J is what separates the volume but I don't really know how to make it think otherwise (if that's the case).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens if you quote it? `docker run -dit -v "J:\dvolumes":/data ubuntu`

Comment: Same issue sadly

Comment: Nevermind it's fixed now

Comment: Thought I'd ask the obvious question before getting into windows idiosyncrasies. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I was trying to run the container in **WSL2** so I should be using linux paths

WSL2

> docker run -dit -v /j/dvolumes:/data ubuntu

Windows

> docker run -dit -v j:/dvolumes:/data ubuntu